# ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

I build a jar file and this jar file was placed on the linux server.
This jar file catches files in specific folder and execute an insert query.
But I got this error.
I have no idea how to solve this. I already searched and tried setting classpath and etc.
How can I build a jar with jdbc.driver jar?
is there anyone who knows this?

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at 
    com.macrogenusa.cjp.ab1.server.DaoManager.updatePlateRun(DaoManager.java:33)
    at UntarFromBoston.update(UntarFromBoston.java:211)
    at UntarFromBoston.run(UntarFromBoston.java:43)
    at UntarFromBoston.main(UntarFromBoston.java:215)
```

Comment: You can try : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: What is the build tool that you're using?

Comment: I tried com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and I use intelliJ